# Web api IgnoreRoute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, swagger, swashbuckle

I've created a v2 version of my api, so I have two controllers:

```
UserController
UserV2Controller
```

And a route set up for

```
"api/v2/user/{action}/{id}"
```

However, the V2 version can also be reached using api/userv2/

I've tried adding

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("IgnoreUserV2", "api/UserV2/{*pathInfo}");
```

to the WebApiConfig (and a similar instruction into Application_Start) but api/userv2 is still available.

I've also removed the default route and created explicit routes for the v1 version but still no luck.

I wouldn't be too bothered, but I've also added Swashbuckle to generate Swagger documentation and it displays both versions of each endpoint which just looks plain odd.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us how do you set up routes?